# Literal ia32-libs in 2017

Tags: 64bit

STOP! Before you tell me "this package has been removed, please use *package-name:i386*" read what I have to say!

I need to use the compression formats of the *PAQ*-family. The executables were made in the ia32-libs era and **they don't accept any replacement for those libs.**
After a lot of unsuccessful research I decided to go through dependency hell and install all ia32-libs dependencies manually, so I can get this package finally to work on my system. First it went well, but now I caught a broken dependency/package error and it seems like this dependency will stay unresolved, which means I can't use the ia32libs package.

What else can I do to make these formats work on my system?

Comment: On what distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re obviously not going to like this answer, but I have the PAQ binaries running fine with `libgcc1:i386`, `libc6:i386`, and `libstdc++6:i386` installed, no `ia32-libs` in sight. For example:

```
$ ldd paq7
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77e8000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf762d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf75d8000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75ba000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7403000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56634000)

$ ./paq7
paq7 compressor/archiver (C) 2005, Matt Mahoney.
Free under GPL, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt

To compress: paq7 [-option] archive files...  (archive will be created)
Or (Windows): dir/b | paq7 archive  (file names read from input)
To decompress/compare: paq7 archive [files...] (defaults to stored names)
To view contents: more < archive

Options are -1 to -5 (use 62, 96, 163, 296, 525 MB memory), default -3
You can't add/extract single files.  Max total file size is 2GB
Time 0.00 sec, memory 8463616 bytes
```

Comment: Doing what you do gives me this:
`./zpaq: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: `ldd zpaq
 linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77a9000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => not found
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7724000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7706000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76e9000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7532000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56606000)
`

Comment: Sorry, I left out `libstdc++6:i386`.

Comment: I searched further in the internet and found the same result you added now: `libstdc++6:i386`.

I installed those and it works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This ppa seems to provide the ZPAQ utilities for post 13.10 ubuntu systems:

https://launchpad.net/~abbat/+archive/ubuntu/zpaq-upstream

Answer (score 0):

It seems that glibc might be the closest what you can get to ia32-libs on a CentOS based system (I'm not 100% sure but it might be). Of course your current system already has glibc installed but only the 64 bit version. So to run 32 bit applications you need the 32 bit version glibc.

To run install glibc in 32 bit run:

yum install glibc.i686

The command above will install glibc.i686 (i*86 = 32 bit architectures) and any dependencies that it might need such as 32 bit versions of other packages.

Try and see if that works.

Source: https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/cento...22428.html